# Private Git Repo - Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Tags: powershell, github

Currently trying to download a file from one of my private Git repositories in Powershell, here's my code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
$wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient; 
$wc.Headers.Add('Authorization','token ------------my token------------'); 
$wc.DownloadFile('https://github.com/Private/Repository/blob/master/hellothere.bat', '%~dp0hello_there.bat');
```

I'm very new to powershell so not sure if this is the way to do it but has been working for me so far when trying to download from public Git repositories. I'm assuming this is happening due to some authentication issue since the connection is being closed, but can't see what is wrong with the syntax and I'm definitely using the correct token.

Any help to get this working is appreciated.

Comment: Your output file intends to have `%~` in its filename?

Comment: No, that's there so that it downloads the file to the same directory where I'm running the script from.

Comment: The source URL also 404s (doesn't exist).  Is this the literal URL you're trying to download?

Comment: Yes there's an actual URL I'm trying to access that I can confirm is accessible. That is just a dummy URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues to figure out here:

1. The `Authorization` header needs to be in the following format:

```
Authorization: bearer ${token}
```

2. The issue was related to GitHub returning a 404 Not Found:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2019 16:48:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: GitHub.com
```

To solve this, you must make sure that you get the URL of the *raw* content of the file like so:

[image]

Then it should work just fine. The final code is identical to yours, just adjusting the header.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
$wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient; 
$wc.Headers.Add('Authorization','bearer $token '); 
$wc.DownloadFile('https://github.com/path/to/raw/file', '/path/to/output');
```

#### Update

If you want to download binaries, then the URL has to change slightly as the binaries are stored elsewhere. Note to future readers, this *may* change.

Currently the format I have it:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$USERNAME/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME/$BINARY_NAME`

Or in my case, it was:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuxhinDB/Test/master/Test.exe`

Comment: I believe this has stopped working as I can't seem to download from my private git repo anymore. The URL is definitely correct and I keep getting a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a lot of trouble with the method above, probably due to changes in the Github API, etc.

Fortunately, after countless attempts, over the course of several weeks, I was ultimately able to find a couple working Solutions.

If you simply want to Download a File from your Private Github Repository, to a specific Location on your Harddrive, you can use the following.

```
$ghtoken = "ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$baseurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$USERNAME/$REPO_NAME/master/$PATH"
$tokenheaders = @{"Authorization"="token $($ghtoken)";"Accept"= "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"}
$scripturl="$($baseurl)/Test.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scripturl -Headers $tokenheaders -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "C:\Temp\Test.exe"
```

However, if you are attempting to Run a Script, such as a PowerShell Script, from your Github Repository, without having to Download the File, try the following.

```
$ghtoken = "ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$baseurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$USERNAME/$REPO_NAME/master/$PATH"
$tokenheaders = @{"Authorization"="token $($ghtoken)";"Accept"= "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"}
$scripturl="$baseurl/Script_To_Run.ps1"
Invoke-Expression(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scripturl -Headers $tokenheaders -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content)
```

I hope this helps someone else, who may be struggling with the same issues, etc.